# SapUi5 cookie get/set

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to use cookies in my SapUI5 application and I want to know if there is any custom way to do it in UI5 (set/get cookie).

I know I can use JavaScript to do it: `document.cookie =  "user=Username;"` for set and than the require code to get it.

It is any specific *class* for managing cookies or best practices regarding SapUi5 Application?

Comment: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/jQuery.sap.storage

Comment: There are no native functionality to working with cookies. Just use storage or cookie over js

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think `jQuery.sap.storage` is the most close thing I was looking for.

Comment: May I kindly ask for what tasks this is needed? I'm just asking for interest

Comment: jquery is deprecated. I suggest https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/module:sap/ui/util/Storage

Comment: Good remark @Marc. I see  `jQuery.sap` is deprecated since version 1.58 when  `sap/ui/util/Storage` was introduced.

Comment: @DubZ I don't have a specific task, I was wanting to learn the SapUI5 good practices  regarding cookies (if any).

Comment: I'm just asking because cookies are different to local storage - also if you can do similar things with it